# How can I change & to &amp; in comment Node using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Is there possible after transform & to amp; in comment Node
**My XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <name>ABCD</name>
    <!--<querycontent><query-number>AQ1:A (Klumin & Koloskov 1982, Lucas 1977, McMurtry 1974, Patrick & Monahan 1957, Plante 1973, Scherer & Cantelon 2013)</query-number></querycontent>-->
</root>
```

**My XSL**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="comment()">
        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**I want to output:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
    <name>ABCD</name>
    <querycontent><query-number>AQ1:A (Klumin &amp; Koloskov 1982, Lucas 1977, McMurtry 1974, Patrick &amp; Monahan 1957, Plante 1973, Scherer &amp; Cantelon 2013)</query-number></querycontent>
</root>
```

If I am convert XML then only change comment node no entity change.
**my output is:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
    <name>ABCD</name>
    <querycontent><query-number>AQ1:A (Klumin & Koloskov 1982, Lucas 1977, McMurtry 1974, Patrick & Monahan 1957, Plante 1973, Scherer & Cantelon 2013)</query-number></querycontent>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&amp;', '&amp;amp;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

But this is just slapping another hack on top of the other two. The real problem here is that the content of the comment is not XML.